# Cancel dropdown behavior on click

Tags: c#, winforms, dropdown

This may seem like a strange request, but I want to cancel the normal behavior of a dropdown control regarding opening or closing the list.  I have several dropdowns on a form and it seemed tedious to have to hit the arrow exactly to open the list.  I added code in the click event handler to open or close the list depending on its current state:

```
    private void customerCodeComboBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customerCodeComboBox.DroppedDown == false)
            customerCodeComboBox.DroppedDown = true;

        else
            customerCodeComboBox.DroppedDown = false;
    }
```

This works just fine unless you actually click on the dropdown arrow.  Then it opens and closes immediately since it fires the normal open and then my code closes it! :(

Is there a way to cancel the normal behavior?  e.Cancel was not available in the EventArgs.  Is there a better way to open the list when a mouse clicks anywhere in the field?

Comment: Presuming you are using a standard Windows Forms ComboBox, it has a `DropDownList` style that works just like this, no other change required. Does this not fulfil your primary requirement?

Comment: What @JayV said. ComboBox Properties > Appearance > DropDownStyle > Change to DropDownList

Comment: Thanks guys!  There are so many properties!  I have been programming for 35 years in various languages but sometimes the simplest solution eludes me.